# First letter always capitalized Delphi xe6 ios

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

Is there a way to toggle the shift key for the iOS virtual keyboard?
When using TEdits, the first letter is always capitalized ( unless password property is set to true ) and I'd rather have it be set to lower case by default. I've found that a workaround is to set the 'keyboardtype' property set to 'NamePhonePad', and this works, but only for the simulator.

Using delphi xe6, developing for iOS

Comment: This is an iOS setting. Try to change it in the Settings/General/Keyboard page.

Comment: This is something I want changed for my application though. In XCode there is a property you can set to determine if you want the first character capitalized or not, but this property is not exposed in Delphi.

Comment: If you just want it for your application you will have to do it yourself by catching the keypress event.

Comment: So, you mean instead of actually toggling the shift key, just change whatever the first key is to lower case? .... hmm... What if the user wants the first letter to be capital though?